# Req.user is undefined when authenticated

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

`req.user` is undefined when user is authenticated. It was working earlier but unsure what i did.

right now, it currently renders

> {}

**routes/user**

```
router.get('/user', (req, res, next) => {
        res.status(200).send({auth: req.user}); // renders {}
});
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var userRoute = require('./routes/users');
var postRoute  = require('./routes/posts');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var models = require('./models');
var User = require('./models/user');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser') ;
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var env = dotenv.config();
var cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
const allowOrigin = process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN || '*'

// CORS Middleware

if (!process.env.PORT) {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

if (!process.env.PORT) {
  console.log('[api][port] 8000 set as default')
  console.log('[api][header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * set as default')
} else {
  console.log('[api][node] Loaded ENV vars from .env file')
  console.log(`[api][port] ${process.env.PORT}`)
  console.log(`[api][header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ${process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN}`)
}


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 


// allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
// res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000'); // your website
// res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
// res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
// res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
// if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
//     res.send(200);
// } else {
//     next();
// }};

app.use(cors({
  origin: process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN,
  credentials:false,
  allowedHeaders: 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, origin, X-Custom-Header',
  methods: 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',

}))

app.use(session({
  secret : 'nodeauthsecret',
  resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: true,

}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/passport')(passport);
require('./config/passport-github')(passport);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user; // This is the important line
  console.log(res.locals.user);
  next();
});

// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
// });



app.use('/api/users', userRoute )
app.use('/api/posts',  postRoute )
```

**passport.js**

```
const BCRYPT_SALT_ROUNDS = 12;

const passport = require('passport'),

  bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
  JWTstrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
  ExtractJWT = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt,
  Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
  Op = Sequelize.Op;

module.exports = function(passport, user) {
  const models = require( '../models/index');
  const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
// serialize session, only store user id in the session information
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  // from the user id, figure out who the user is...
  passport.deserializeUser(function(userId, done){
    models.User
      .find({ where: { id: userId } })
      .then(function(user){
        done(null, user);
      }).catch(function(err){
        done(err, null);
      });
  });

  passport.use(
    'register',
    new localStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true,
        session: false,
      },
      (req, username, password, done) => {
        try {
           models.User.findOne({
            where: {
              [Op.or]: [
                {
                  username: username,
                },
                { email: req.body.email },
              ],
            },
          }).then(user => {
            if (user != null) {
              console.log('username or email already taken');
              return done(null, false, {
                message: 'username or email already taken',
              });
            } else {
              bcrypt.hash(password, BCRYPT_SALT_ROUNDS).then(hashedPassword => {
                models.User.create({
                  username: req.body.username,
                  password: hashedPassword,
                  email: req.body.email
                }).then(user => {
                  console.log('user created');
                  return done(null, user);
                });
              });
            }
          });
        } catch (err) {
          done(err);
        }
      },
    ),
  );



passport.use(
  'login',
  new localStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'username',
      passwordField: 'password',
      session: false
    },
    (username, password, done, req) => {
      try {
        models.User.findOne({
          where: {
            [Op.or]: [
              {
                username: username,
              }
            ],
          },
        }).then(user => {
          if (user === null) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Username doesn\'t exist' });

          } else {
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(response => {
              if (response !== true) {
                console.log('passwords do not match');
                return done(null, false, { message: 'passwords do not match' });
              }

              console.log('user found & authenticated');
              // note the return needed with passport local - remove this return for passport JWT
              return done(null, user);
            });


          }
        });
      } catch (err) {
        done(err);
      }
    },
  ),
);

const opts = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT'),
  secretOrKey: process.env.jwtsecret,
};




passport.use(
  'jwt',
  new JWTstrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    try {
       models.User.findOne({
        where: {
          username: jwt_payload._id,
        },
      }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
          console.log('user found in db in passport');
          // note the return removed with passport JWT - add this return for passport local
          done(null, user);
          // console.log(user);
        } else {
          console.log('user not found in db');
          done(null, false);
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      done(err);
    }
  }),
);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

when succesfully signed in do

```
req.user = user;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `passport.js` file, you should remove

```
const passport = require('passport'),
```

as you are passing this in from `app.js`

Answer (score 0):

it appears that adding this on the top of above my routes and session variables seemed to give me access to req.user

```
// CORS Middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var userRoute = require('./routes/users');
var postRoute  = require('./routes/posts');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var models = require('./models');
var User = require('./models/user');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser') ;
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var env = dotenv.config();
var cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
const allowOrigin = process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN || '*'

// CORS Middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});



if (!process.env.PORT) {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

if (!process.env.PORT) {
  console.log('[api][port] 8000 set as default')
  console.log('[api][header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * set as default')
} else {
  console.log('[api][node] Loaded ENV vars from .env file')
  console.log(`[api][port] ${process.env.PORT}`)
  console.log(`[api][header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ${process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN}`)
}

app.use(cors({
  origin: process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN,
  credentials:false,
  allowedHeaders: 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, origin, X-Custom-Header',
  methods: 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',

}))
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false })); 




app.use(session({
  secret : process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  resave: false,
 saveUninitialized:true,

}));



app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/passport')(passport);
require('./config/passport-github')(passport);
app.use('/api/users', userRoute )
app.use('/api/posts',  postRoute )
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user; // This is the important line
  console.log(res.locals.user);
  next();
});





app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('[api][listen] http://localhost:' + port)
})
```